# Calculating flow rate from a given water tank and water head in hydropower

Tags: waste-water-treatment, hydroelectric-dams

I'm calculating feasibility of using grey water in high rise buildings to generate hydroelectricity.

Let's assume a given water volume of 100 cubic meters a day and a water head of 100 meter. What should be the diameter of the pipe and thus what should be the flow rate in order to maximise the total power generated through the turbine? Lets assume emptying the tank will be done once (or more) a day.

Comment: Your application is the same as the hydroelectric power generating facility using the pumped-storage method - generating electricity during the peak usage period of the day, then the water in the lower reservoir was pumped back to the higher reservoir during low demand period. The difficulty here is you need sizable batteries to store the unused electricity though.

Comment: If you want to size your pipes, you need to have an idea of how much frictional energy loss you can tolerate before the turbine. You should also keep in mind if you need to the fluid to retain any amount of excess pressure/energy downstream of the turbine to make sure the water will flow to where it needs to go. A sketch showing the starting and ending points of the water and any equipment in between would be good to share.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's assume a given water volume of 100 cubic meters a day and a water head of 100 meter.

- 100 m<sup>3</sup> = 100 T = 100,000 kg. That's a lot of weight and a lot of valuable space in a high rise building.
- Averaged out it's about 4000 kg per hour.
- The potential energy of one hour's worth is given by $mgh = 4000 \times 9.81 \times 100 = 4000 \ \mathrm {kJ} $
- Releasing 4000 kg in one hour gives an average power of $ \frac {4000}{3600} \ \mathrm {kJ/s} = 1.1 \ \mathrm {kW} $. All of this assumes 100% efficiency.
- 1.1 kW at, say, €0.15 /kWh and 8,760 h/year = €1,314 per year payback.

> What should be the diameter of the pipe and thus what should be the flow rate in order to maximise the total power generated through the turbine?

I don't know but the average flow is 1.16 L/s which doesn't sound like too much.

> Lets assume emptying the tank will be done once ( or more ) a day.

Let's not. You would have to size the pipework and turbine for very high capacity and low utilisation. This would be poor economics. Instead it would be sized to cope with worst case hourly load in conjunction with the storage.

I'd say it's a waste of time and money.

Comment: @yon1000 I think at this moment you need to find a turbine that can produce that amount of power, its efficiency, and the flow rate required (from the manufacturer) to drive the turbine. Note that you can calculate the discharge velocity from the head, once the flow rate is known, you can size the pipe accordingly. The design will require several iterations though.